# What is the build command for react app created with bun js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, bun

#### Installed `bun` version is

```bash
bun -v 
0.1.2
```

#### I created a react app with the following command

```bash
bun create react my-bun-app
```

#### To run it I am using the following command

```bash
cd my-bun-app
bun dev
```

#### Now I want to know what is the `build` command for building the react app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a React app with bun, you need to install react-scripts. You can do that with `bun a react-scripts`. Then just run `bun react-scripts build`.

Answer (score 0):

1. To build a React app with bun, you need to install react-scripts.
   You can do that with `bun a react-scripts`.
2. Then add
   `"build": "react-scripts build"`
   in **package.json** inside the `scripts`
3. Then just run bun `react-scripts build`.